# How to install/import Biopython into Python 3.8/ PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, software-installation

I'm new to Python/Biopython programming. I'd like to install Biopython into my PyCharm IDE but I've tried all instructions on this, but it's not confirming it. I have the available biopython file already extracted. There's a SyntaxError for 'install' in:
pip install biopython
What's the proper way of installing and importing biopython? And how does one confirm the installation.

Comment: You probably should mention your operating system.

Comment: Could you please show the complete error text? Which python version do you use?

Comment: A SyntaxError is an exception raised by python, so I guess you ran pip within the python interpreter rather than from your shell/terminal

Comment: @WouterDeCoster It's Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit OS, 4gb RAM

Comment: @Mr_Z Python 3.8, PyCharm 2020.1.2.        Here: pip install biopython
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install biopython
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Anaconda3 the instructions are [here](https://www.google.co.uk/m?q=conda%20creating%20an%20environment&client=ms-opera-mobile&channel=new&espv=1#). Then making sure you are connected to the internet type

```
conda install -c anaconda biopython
```

Once Anaconda is installed don't attempt to use `pip`, if you do then you need to set an 'environment' in Anaconda and work from that environment.

I suspect you used `pip` or `pip3` via

```
pip install biopython
```